# Instruments viewcontroller segue not released?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, swift, storyboard, segue

I have a question about Storyboard, Segues and memory management.  If I read about it on forums people say this is working properly but I was wondering the following, I made a small video to illustrate:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixs1Fiv5M9s

1. I grabbed a source from github explaining segues and unwinding them
2. I tested this in debugging and indeed I see all functions including dealloc is working
3. I run instruments and check how many times 2de view controller is created (every time #Persistent is increasing)
4. I check for changes in memory between the 2 states, and a lot is still in memory?  But View controller is gone?

I am looking for the wrong data in instruments?  I guess looking for memory leaks using modal and dismissing a view controller is not the right way to do this?

Can somebody explain me how to look for memory leaks?  I need this for a much bigger app that is using a lot of segues, and sometimes this app crashes because of memory warnings...

Comment: Your video is flagged as private. Cannot watch it.

Comment: sorry, changed it to unlisted now